# Machine epsilon: why is $(1 + \epsilon) + \epsilon = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, floating-point, machine-precision

My book on real analysis has the following statement:

[image]

I don't understand how the first equation can possibly be true, by definition of machine epsilon.

**Machine epsilon** is defined as the smallest number that, when added to the number $1$, will yield the next representable machine number in our floating-point system that is $> 1$. In other words, it is the distance between the number $1$ and the next machine number to the right of $1$.

By this definition, that means:

$(1 + \epsilon) > 1$

So, how is it possible that adding $\epsilon$ yet again will produce $1$ itself? That seems paradoxical.

Comment: The passage clearly states that $\epsilon < \epsilon_{\text{mach}}$

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that... I can't read properly when I'm tired and angry at Math. So yes, by definition, that makes sense. If $\epsilon < \epsilon_{mach}$, then $1 + \epsilon$ gets rounded down to $1$, then add $\epsilon$ again and you're basically still stuck at $1$.

Comment: Yep exactly! Just add the constraint that $\epsilon \geq \frac{\epsilon_{\text{mach}}}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Interesting, I think I'm close to understanding why that condition is required, but it hasn't quite yet clicked. Could you clarify? I see Servaes noted it as well.

Comment: For example, what happens if $\epsilon < \frac{\epsilon_{mach}}{2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted text states that $\epsilon$ is slightly smaller that $\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$. This implies $1+\epsilon=1$ and hence also $(1+\epsilon)+\epsilon=1$, but if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently large, i.e. $\epsilon\geq\tfrac12\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$, then
$$1+(\epsilon+\epsilon)\geq1+\epsilon_{\text{mach}}>1.$$

Comment: Thanks! See my comment above under the OP. I'm wondering why we need the constraint of epsilon being greater than or equal to 0.5 machine epsilon.